# How to add tint color to material in Scene Kit in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, 3d, scenekit

I'm making a game in SceneKit, and I need to add a tint to an image that is used as the material for a box. How would I go about adding a blue tint to the material/image?

**This is my code**

```
let material = SCNMaterial()

let whiteSquare = UIImage(named: "whiteSquare.png")

let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.2, length: 0.5, chamferRadius: 0))

material.diffuse.contents = whiteSquare
boxNode.position.z = -1.25
boxNode.position.y = 0.1
boxNode.name = "Block\(height)"
boxNode.geometry?.materials = [material]
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

Comment: might need to render first...